# Nginx - Mapping subdomain

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up a subdomain on my digitalocean droplet that maps to a static html file. Currently, my nginx .conf file looks like this:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    }
}

server{
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;
    location / {
            root    /var/www/subdomain-dir;
            index   index.html;
    }
}
```

On example.com I'm running a node server on port 4000 and everything works great. On subdomain.example.com, I'd like to serve just a static html file that sits in the `/var/www/subdomain` path. That part is not working. I've verified that the file and filepath is correct and that I restarted the nginx server. I'm wondering if maybe the issue has something to do with the port, however, in the end, I'm just lost as to what the problem is. When I browse to the subdomain.example.com, it says `This webpage is not available`.

**UPDATE/EDIT**

Here is the access.log and error.log:

```
==> access.log.1 <==
180.76.4.226 - - [14/Mar/2015:19:17:31 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
180.76.4.135 - - [14/Mar/2015:21:18:35 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
149.129.42.215 - - [14/Mar/2015:21:19:51 -0400] "GET /tmUnblock.cgi HTTP/1.1" 400 181 "-" "-"
180.76.4.19 - - [14/Mar/2015:23:26:26 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12805 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
207.46.13.126 - - [15/Mar/2015:01:06:39 -0400] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 177 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
207.46.13.126 - - [15/Mar/2015:01:06:43 -0400] "GET /capture.php HTTP/1.1" 404 151 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
180.76.4.9 - - [15/Mar/2015:01:19:23 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
38.100.21.67 - - [15/Mar/2015:02:57:22 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2)"
180.76.4.156 - - [15/Mar/2015:03:18:33 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"
180.76.4.181 - - [15/Mar/2015:05:21:35 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)"

==> error.log.1 <==
2015/03/10 18:16:42 [emerg] 29461#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:16:42 [emerg] 29461#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:16:42 [emerg] 29461#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:16:42 [emerg] 29461#0: still could not bind()
2015/03/10 18:17:01 [emerg] 29499#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:17:01 [emerg] 29499#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:17:01 [emerg] 29499#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:17:01 [emerg] 29499#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:17:01 [emerg] 29499#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2015/03/10 18:17:01 [emerg] 29499#0: still could not bind()
```

Comment: Provide nginx logs of failed request please.

Comment: I think it's wrong logs:) If it's really requests to subdomain, your problem is nginx isn't serving them itself but instead passes them to proxy. Please recheck your configuration, possible problem might be using `.example.com` instead of `example.com`, which reads as `*.example.com example.com` and might catch your subdomain too.